# How do Android app knows that the underlying hardware supports a certain hardware decoding accelaration?

Tags: android, linux, codec

I just bought a TV box powered by Android 2.3. The underlying hardware platform is centered on Telechip 8801, which bases on ARM Cortex A8 and supports hardware media codec. However, when I play some video on it, it is not so smooth.  The problem is that the media player doesn't take advantages of the underlying hardware codec. **So, my question is that how upper app framework or apps knows media acceleration features of hardware and how to make use of them. TKs.**

Answer (score 0):

Apps wont know about the underlying HW. They just call some APIs which in turn call lower level drivers which actually have the responsibility of interacting with the HW. So the HW vendor( or the one who wrote the device driver )  of your TV Box should have implemented the media related drivers in such a way that it takes advantage of the HW accelerator. Android Framework has nothing to do with it!

Also, how are you sure that your Box is not utilizing the HW accelerator?

Comment: I have installed Rockplayer in the system, which allows us to select to use hardware acceleration or not. When I selected it, it play perfect; if not, it played awfully. When I used adobe flash player to play some online videos, it doesn't seem to have leveraged the hardware acceleration.  If I would like to make adobe flash player to use the hardware codec, I am wondering what I should begin with. Tks for your valuable answer.